Connect mulesoft api to vb.net console application
I am developing a .NET Framework 4.0 console application in VB.NET. I'm trying to connect to an API using HttpWebRequest, but I keep encountering the following error:

System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'
IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Code:
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' Set the API URL
        Dim apiUrl As String = "your_api_url_here"

        Console.WriteLine(apiUrl)

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(apiUrl), HttpWebRequest)

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module


You haven't provided any details of the API for us to be able to help you. The fact that it may be implemented in Mule or not doesn't seem to be relevant. You need to provide more details. What is the authentication required? Does it uses TLS mutual authentication? Version of TLS sent by the client? Have you tried to capture the traffic and analyze it?
